# Python UnicodeEncodeError when writing to file

Tags: python, file, unicode, pdfminer

I'm using "pdfminer.six", a python library, to extract all text from a few PDFs I have. My method works flawlessly, but with some pdfs, that probably have a few characters in special, when I'm writing it to a text file, I get "Unicode Encode Error: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 271130: character maps to ".
Now, I know what "is" happening, but I'd like to know how to treat it the best way. This is the part that is giving me a headache:

```
    with open("newTxtFile.txt", "w") as textFile:
        textFile.write(text)
```

Since I'm from Brazil and the text is in portuguese, I want to keep all accentuation, so I use "codec = 'latin-1'" with pdfminer. Printing before saving, as far as I could check, works flawlessly until the end, but whenever I try saving to file, I get UnicodeEncodeError.

My two options that I thought about are:
Either I find a way to catch only the specific character that is giving me trouble:

```
    with open("newTxtFile.txt", "w") as textFile:
    try:
        textFile.write(text)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        ????
```

But I don't know what should be in the except?

Or I should save differently to the file.

Can anyone give me a few tips? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What actual `UnicodeEncodeError` do you get?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko Unicode Encode Error: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 271130: character maps to undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
with open("newTxtFile.txt", "wb") as textFile:
    textFile.write(text.encode('utf8'))
```

to read it:

```
with open("newTxtFile.txt", "rb") as textFile:
    text = textFile.read().decode('utf8')
```

Comment: My text type is Str. If I do with this encoding, it gives me "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes". Also, wouldn't utf-8 mess up with all the accents and special characters in portuguese language?

Comment: @fallremix utf-8 is one of the most complete encoding so I don't think it would mess up I've edited my post with 'wb' instead of 'w' open mode

Comment: It works! I just have to decode it afterwards. Kinda weird because almost all of my other pdf files have been saved without errors, only a few were giving me this headache.

Comment: Explicit encoding/decoding is not needed.  Use `with open(...,encoding='utf8')` (Python 3) or `with io.open(...,encoding='utf8')` (Python 2 or 3) and read/write Unicode strings.